# Extract value from Stripe object

Tags: php, stripe-payments

How do I get the value of 'name'?

I've been trying various methods, including array($charge) and __toArray.

First works, second does not:

```
$charge_id = $charge->id;
echo $charge_id;
$name=$charge->_values->name;
echo $name;
```

Here is portion of the object returned by Stripe (up to the name I want to extract):

```
Stripe\Charge::__set_state(array(
   '_opts' => 
  Stripe\Util\RequestOptions::__set_state(array(
     'headers' => 
    array (
    ),
     'apiKey' => 'sk_test_...',
  )),
   '_values' => 
  array (
    'id' => 'ch_73JaKii01nmbpZ',
    'object' => 'charge',
    'created' => 1443251926,
    'livemode' => false,
    'paid' => true,
    'status' => 'succeeded',
    'amount' => 1000,
    'currency' => 'usd',
    'refunded' => false,
    'source' => 
    Stripe\Card::__set_state(array(
       '_opts' => 
      Stripe\Util\RequestOptions::__set_state(array(
         'headers' => 
        array (
        ),
         'apiKey' => 'sk_test_...',
      )),
       '_values' => 
      array (
        'id' => 'card_73JZrJCDzl877J',
        'object' => 'card',
        'last4' => '1111',
        'brand' => 'Visa',
        'funding' => 'unknown',
        'exp_month' => 12,
        'exp_year' => 2021,
        'fingerprint' => 'hhzQQZIXaAVDNMPP',
        'country' => 'US',
        'name' => 'Steve Veltkamp',
```

Answer (score 3):

according to this:
https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php/blob/master/lib/Charge.php

you may try to play with `retrieve` method:

```
$charge::retrieve($charge->id);
```

or ( https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php/blob/master/lib/StripeObject.php ):

```
$chargeArr = $charge->__toArray(true);
```

add `true` as argument for recursion

Answer (score 3):

(Note: you should edit your question to remove your secret key and replace it with e.g. `'sk_test_...'`. Even if it's just a test key, secret keys are not meant to be shared.)

The property you're trying to access is the cardholder's name. The `source` attribute of a [charge object](https://stripe.com/docs/api/php#charge_object) is actually a [card object](https://stripe.com/docs/api/php#card_object):

```
php > echo get_class($charge);
Stripe\Charge

php > echo get_class($charge->source);
Stripe\Card
```

So to get the cardholder's name, all you have to do is:

```
$name = $charge->source->name;
```

Note that `name` is an optional attribute for cards, so it's possible that you'll get `NULL`, an empty string, an email address, etc.